# Actions intended to be detected/handled by Ngrx Effects are not working: could Lazyloading Modules be the cause?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am dispatching a Ngrx action in my (root) App module (in AppComponent), which should be handled through an effect but this effect is not being trigged.
The effect is declared/implemented in some other lazy-loading angular module and I am presuming that lazyloading could be the clue.

I suppose that since my lazy module has not been loaded yet, there is no way for angular to know that the effects is there to be picked up, although the effect is declared in my list of effects (EffectsModule.forFeature(...).
I am sure that the lazyloading module is not loaded, because the route which triggers the lazy loading of the corresponding module has not been triggered yet.

To verify/validate my assumption I made the lazyloading module eager by adding the module to my root module's import and the action was detected and handled this time by the effect.

*Is this a lack of design in my app or is there a pattern/best practise for dealing with this situation?*

Answer (score 1):

Your findings are correct.
An Effect is only registered when the lazy loaded Angular module is loaded.
Also fyi, the same stands for feature reducers.

In most of the cases this means that you need to lift that state up to the root module. You can do this by eagerly loading the module, this means that the Angular components are also loaded.
Or you can move the effect/reducer to the root state.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I understand your suggestion/point. I guess there should be a way to let a dispatch action trigger a lazy-loading module, so that this module is loaded and the effects in this module would be initialised and triggered. I am not sure whether the Angular framework would give sufficient hooks, so that Ngrx/effects could handle this situation. Would be great. It would be a waste to declare my modules eager for the sole reason of making some Ngrx effects detectable.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on timdeschryver's answer some:

****Lazy loading strategies**** - Eager loading does introduce additional load time when the user first pulls up the application. One of the alternatives is [Preloading Module](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading-modules). This method loads only what is needed by the user when the page is first loaded, and then begins to load additional modules in the background unbeknownst to the user. This *might* solve your problem, depending on when certain actions are dispatched and when you expect the Effect to be available.

****Root State****

I've used this in the past:

```
src/
  app/

    // main, necessary application components/services
    core/

    // all lazy loaded modules
    features/

    // shared components/directives/etc
    shared/
    
    // all ngrx-related state
    root-state/
      root-store.module.ts
      root.effects.ts
      feature1-state/
        feature1-state.module.ts
      feature2-state/
        feature2-state.module.ts
```

In the above scenario, `root-store.module.ts` imports all feature state modules, registers all feature Effects.. basically handles everything state related. Then, in `app.module.ts` you only have to import RootStoreModule. This also increases the initial load time (slightly), but ensures all of your state/effects are available from the start. (All interaction with state data is done via Facade services in feature modules that get lazy loaded)

Lastly, after digging a little, I found [this blog post](https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/manually-lazy-load-modules-and-components-in-angular/) which introduces the concept of using a service to programmatically call `import('../path/to/lazy/module').then(m => m.FeatureModule)` just like you would use in a Routing module. I haven't tried this, but if it works as described that could easily be added as an Effect for lazy module loading on demand.